# BottomAppBar raises while using soft keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-bottomappbar

I'm trying to hide *BottomAppBar* behind keyboard but when I change focus to another *EditText* the part of *BottomAppBar* start to appear like in  [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yCrN.jpg) . Also I have already tried change *windowSoftInputMode* but I really need *adjustPan*.

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fabCradleMargin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="@dimen/fab_corner_radius"
        app:hideOnScroll="false"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:transitionName="bottom_appbar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar" />

     <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/bottom_fab"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/floatButtonColor"
        app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this to your `<activity>` tag in the manifest

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"`

Comment: @Satyavrat I need adjustPan, because it should focus on input field (((

Comment: @VladislavYakubovsky then set this in bottom so it will not visible above keyboard like if you are using relative layout set align parent bottom= true

Comment: @Satyavrat, I'm using CoordinatorLayout (because BottomAppBar must have it as a parent) and I'm using layout_gravity=bottom but it doesn't help

Comment: but you can have relative layout inside CoordinatorLayout

Comment: @Satyavrat, BottomAppBar must be a direct child of CoordinatorLayout